# Clone a row in an HTML table and call JavaScript function with the new row

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table which has one row in which I multiply two fields, namely quantity and rate/quantity, to get the product total.  I have provided a button to add a new row which basically clones the 1st row.  Now I want the cloned row to also have the same product as the 1st row.  I have tried the following code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <h3 align="center">K J Somaiya College Of Engineering, Vidyavihar, Mumbai-400 077</h3>
    <h3 align="center">Department Of Information Technology</h3>
    <body>
     <script>
     function WO1() {

     var qty = document.getElementById('qty').value;

var price = document.getElementById('price').value;

answer = (Number(qty) * Number(price)).toFixed(2);  

document.getElementById('totalprice').value = answer;   
}

function WO2() {

var qty = document.getElementById('qty1').value;

var price = document.getElementById('price1').value;

answer = (Number(qty) * Number(price)).toFixed(2);  

document.getElementById('totalprice1').value = answer;   
}

function WO3() {

var qty = document.getElementById('qty2').value;

var price = document.getElementById('price2').value;

answer = (Number(qty) * Number(price)).toFixed(2);

document.getElementById('totalprice2').value = answer;
}
</script>
<script>
function validateNumbe()
{
var x=document.getElementById("floor").value;
if (x==null || x=="")
{
alert("Floor must be entered");
return false;
}
}

function validateN()
{
var x=document.getElementById("lab").value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
 alert("Laboratory Name must be entered");
 return false;
  }
}

function validateNumb()
{
var x=document.getElementById("room").value;
if (x==null || x=="")
 {
 alert("Room No must be entered");
 return false;
 }
}

function validateNum()
{
var x=document.getElementById("labi").value;
if (x==null || x=="")
 {
 alert("Name of Laboratory Incharge must be entered");
 return false;
 }
}

function validateNu()
{
var x=document.getElementById("year").value;
if (x==null || x=="")
 {
 alert("Budget for the year must be entered");
  return false;
}
}


</script>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="10">
<tr>
<td align="left">Date:<input type="date" name="date"/></td>
<td align="right">Floor: <input type="text" id="floor" onchange="validateNumbe()"       

onblur="validateNumbe()"/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left">Laboratory Name: <input type="text" id="lab" onchange="validateN()"        

onblur="validateN()"/></td>
<td align="right">Room no: <input type="text" id="room" onchange="validateNumb()"       

onblur="validateNumb()"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left">Name of Laboratory Incharge: <input type="text" id="labi"      

onchange="validateNum()"  onblur="validateNum()"/></td>
<td align="right">Budget for the year: <input type="text" id="year" onchange="validateNu()"     

onblur="validateNu()"/></td>
</tr>
</table>


<h3 align="left"><b>Computer</b><h3>
<table id="POITable" border="1" width="100%">
 <tr>
    <td style="width:10%">Sr No.</td>
    <td>Item Description</td>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td>Rate(Inclusive of Taxes)</td>
    <td>Total Cost</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comp_item"></textarea></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='Quantity' id='qty' class="qty" placeholder='Qty' /></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='Rate' id='price' class="price" placeholder='Price (&pound;)'   

onChange="WO1()" /></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='Total' id='totalprice' class="price" placeholder='Total    

Price&nbsp;(&pound;)' /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
 <input type="button" id="addmorePOIbutton" value="Add New Row"/>

 <h3 align="left"><b>Equipment</b><h3>
<table id="POITable1" border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th style="width:10%">Sr No.</th>
        <th>Item Description</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Rate(Inclusive of Taxes)</th>
        <th>Total Cost</th>
      </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
    <td><textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comp_item"></textarea></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='Quantity' id='qty1' class="qty" placeholder='Qty' /></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='Rate' id='price1' class="price" placeholder='Price (&pound;)'  

onChange="WO2()" /></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='Total' id='totalprice1' class="price" placeholder='Total   

Price&nbsp;(&pound;)' /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
 <input type="button" id="addmorePOIbutton1" value="Add New Row"/>

    <h3 align="left"><b>Furniture</b><h3>
<table id="POITable2" border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th style="width:10%">Sr No.</th>
        <th>Item Description</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Rate(Inclusive of Taxes)</th>
        <th>Total Cost</th>
      </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
    <td><textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comp_item"></textarea></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='Quantity' id='qty2' class="qty" placeholder='Qty' /></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='Rate' id='price2' class="price" placeholder='Price (&pound;)'  

onChange="WO3()" /></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='Total' id='totalprice2' class="price" placeholder='Total   

Price&nbsp;(&pound;)' /></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <input type="button" id="addmorePOIbutton2" value="Add New Row"/>

<script>

 ( function() { // Prevent vars from leaking to the global scope

  var formTable = document.getElementById('POITable');
  var newRowBtn = document.getElementById('addmorePOIbutton');


  newRowBtn.addEventListener('click', insRow, false); //added eventlistener insetad of inline   

onclick-attribute.

  function insRow() {
    var new_row = formTable.rows[1].cloneNode(true),
    numTableRows = formTable.rows.length;

    // Set the row number in the first cell of the row
    new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = numTableRows;

    numTableRows=numTableRows - 1;
    var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
    inp1.name += numTableRows;
    inp1.value = '';

    var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp2.name += numTableRows;
    inp2.value = '';

    var inp3 = new_row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp3.name += numTableRows;
    inp3.value = '';

    var inp4 = new_row.cells[4].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp4.name += numTableRows;
    inp4.value = '';

    // Append the new row to the table
    formTable.appendChild( new_row );

  }


  var formTable1 = document.getElementById('POITable1');
  var newRowBtn1 = document.getElementById('addmorePOIbutton1');

  newRowBtn1.addEventListener('click', insRow1, false); //added eventlistener insetad of inline     

onclick-attribute.


  function insRow1() {
    var new_row = formTable1.rows[1].cloneNode(true),
    numTableRows = formTable1.rows.length;

    // Set the row number in the first cell of the row
    new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = numTableRows;

    numTableRows=numTableRows - 1;
    var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
    inp1.name += numTableRows;
    inp1.value = '';

    var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp2.name += numTableRows;
    inp2.value = '';

    var inp3 = new_row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp3.name += numTableRows;
    inp3.value = '';

    var inp4 = new_row.cells[4].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp4.name += numTableRows;
    inp4.value = '';

    // Append the new row to the table
    formTable1.appendChild( new_row );


  }





  var formTable2 = document.getElementById('POITable2');
  var newRowBtn2 = document.getElementById('addmorePOIbutton2');

  newRowBtn2.addEventListener('click', insRow2, false); //added eventlistener insetad of inline     

onclick-attribute.


  function insRow2() {
    var new_row = formTable2.rows[1].cloneNode(true),
    numTableRows = formTable2.rows.length;

    // Set the row number in the first cell of the row
    new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = numTableRows;

    numTableRows=numTableRows - 1;
    var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
    inp1.name += numTableRows;
    inp1.value = '';

    var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp2.name += numTableRows;
    inp2.value = '';

    var inp3 = new_row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp3.name += numTableRows;
    inp3.value = '';

    var inp4 = new_row.cells[4].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp4.name += numTableRows;
    inp4.value = '';

    // Append the new row to the table
    formTable2.appendChild( new_row );


   }

     })();

  function myfun()
 {


var lun= document.getElementById('POITable').rows.length;
 document.getElementsByName("len")[0].value = lun-1;

   var lun1= document.getElementById('POITable1').rows.length;
 document.getElementsByName("len1")[0].value = lun1-1;

 var lun2= document.getElementById('POITable2').rows.length;
 document.getElementsByName("len2")[0].value = lun2-1;

 }


 function myFunction()
{
window.print();

}

</script>


<input type="hidden" name="len" value="1">

<input type="hidden" name="len1" value="1">
<input type="hidden"  name="len2" value="1">


<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td><br><br><br></td>
<td><br><br><br></td>
<td><br><br><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left">Signature <br>Lab-In-Charge</td>
<td align="center">Signature<br>Lab Assistant</td>
<td align="right">Signature <br>Head of Department</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br><br><br>

<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" onclick='this.form.action="archive.php";myfun();'>
<input type="submit" value="SAVE AND CONTINUE LATER"            

onclick='this.form.action="myphpformhandler.php";myfun();'>
</form>
<h3 align="center"><button onclick="myFunction()"><h3>Print this page</h3></button></h3>


</body>
</html>
```

i have created the JSFiddle but the multiplication is not working in it.

http://jsfiddle.net/xkY4Z/2/

Comment: Your html doesn't have a head section…
btw can you make a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with all that..?

Comment: i have created the JSFiddle but the multiplication is not working in it.

http://jsfiddle.net/xkY4Z/2/

Comment: @user3548277 to make function's work in jsfiddle you must select `no wrap- in <body>` on top left hand side to include your javascript code within your body... [Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/xkY4Z/6/)

Comment: how do i make the multiplication(product of quantity and Rate) possible for the new row that is created by clicking on add new row button?

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution to your problem but a bit closer  ***[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xkY4Z/7/)***
Done using jQuery

```
$(document).on('change','input', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split("-");
    var answer = (Number($('#qty-' + id[1]).val()) * Number($('#price-' + id[1]).val())).toFixed(2);
    $('#totalprice-' + id[1]).val(answer);
});
```

---

***Update***

### ***[Working Fiddle with name](http://jsfiddle.net/xkY4Z/10/)***

---

***Latest***

### ***[Fiddle with Grand total](http://jsfiddle.net/xkY4Z/17/)***

Comment: Well Bhavik firstly thanx alot for your solution..
Secondly cant we do it using javascript..?

Comment: @Uttam It could be done using javascript... But using jQuery will be a lot shorter and even easily manageable...

Comment: You have used id in the function inorder to access form data
Can we use the name attribute?
because i have to pass this form data to a PHP file in which name attribute is used every where.

Comment: thanx alot Bhavik
your help proved to be very useful for me.

Comment: if i add a textbox(total) at the right most end of the table then how can i sum all the values in the TOTAL COST column and display the result in this textbox(total)
check out the updated FIDDLE
http://jsfiddle.net/xkY4Z/13/

Comment: Thank You Bhavik for your Valuable Help
But i need a textbox(total) which should be updated automatically when i enter different values in the table
you have given a button(calculate total)
can u give a textbox which directly displays the total based on onclick event or something
also i need a GRAND TOTAL textbox which gives the sum of all the total entries(sum of all the total textbox below each table)

Comment: @Uttam [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xkY4Z/17/)... Also, if this answered solved your purpose, you must mark it as answered... It might help someone